# C# - Extend StorageFile class to add a custom string property

Tags: c#

In my windows store app i save files in this way:

```
StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName.Replace('/', '_'),
                CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

Now i want to add an identifier, a string, to the file so that i can access this property in another moment.

I thought to override the CreateFileAsync method but it does not work:

```
public class MyStorageFolder : StorageFolder
{
    public async Task<MyStorageFile> CreateFileAsync(string x)
    {            
        MyStorageFile file =  (MyStorageFile) await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(x.Replace('/', '_'));

        return file;
    }

}

public class MyStorageFile : StorageFile
{
    private string _objectId = string.Empty;
    public string ObjectId
    {
        get { return this._objectId; }
        set { this._objectId = value }
    }
}
```

I receive an error "Cannot conver type StorageFile to MyStorageFile"...is there a way to do this??!?!

[EDIT]: Really interesting...at Runtime i receive an error:'MyStorageFolder': cannot derive from sealed type 'StorageFolder'...so i need a complitely alternative way to do store the information i need!!!

Answer (score 1):

[Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

```
public class MyStorageFile {
    StorageFile File { get; set; }
    String MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyStorageFolder : StorageFolder {
    public async Task<MyStorageFile> CreateFileAsync(string x)
    {             
        MyStorageFile file = new MyStorageFile();         
        file.File =  (MyStorageFile) await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(x.Replace('/', '_'));
            return file;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but if i get the file later, localFolder.GetFileAsync(x), i will lose the MyProperty information!

Comment: I was thinking this is the right solution but the class StorageFile is sealed so i can''t extend it...have you an idea?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. Create StorageFile class extensions and read/write your content asyncronously.

```
async public static Task WriteAllTextAsync(this StorageFile storageFile, string content) 
        { 
            var inputStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite); 
            var writeStream = inputStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0); 
            DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(writeStream); 
            writer.WriteString(content); 
            await writer.StoreAsync(); 
            await writeStream.FlushAsync(); 
        }
```

The code was taken from the following link :
http://dotnetspeak.com/2011/10/reading-and-writing-files-in-winrt

Comment: Thank you for your answer...but i don't want to write a string INTO the file...i want to associate to the file an information, a string, that i will use in the future...

Comment: If this information you are refering to can be injected inside the stream and retrieved later you can do something like that: dataWriter.WriteUInt32(yourId); dataWriter.WriteString(content); and then when reading, take the int id first and then the string content. That way you are associating your stream with an id. Perhaps not the ideal way, but if there are any other more elegant ways I'd be willing to learn as well